# Multiple home page in magento in a single installation and single store and single storeview

Tags: magento, html

I want to achieve 2 home pages in a `single installation` of magento and with `single store`.

Firs one is an animated intro made in css page transitions. Which will have menus like
Home, Brands, Collection, Socialize, Contact. Out of them when you click on collection you will be on a `new tab` where you will see the  complete `ecommerce website`. But both the homepages have different design and should be in a single installation.

Is it possible to achieve, if yes please give some guidelines. I am not a beginner i have done projects in magento. Simple explanation will do.

Comment: Do you mean that the homepage will only be viewable when you first hit the site, but on subsequent visits it wont be available?

Comment: It will be available because it is already opened in the tab no.1.
Firstly when you go to the domain name FIRST homepage will display and then when you want to see the collection you will click on collection link, then it will take you to ANTHER TAB in the browser. And there you will see the SECOND homepage.

Comment: So, you don't need two homepages.  You need a homepage (that the customer will see whenever they hit the domain) and then you just need a CMS page that you redirect them to in a new tab when they click on something? (i.e. create a page /collection/ ?)

Comment: domain.com/collection/ will a magento theme i have purchased from themeforest.
and domain.com will be homepage that i will create.
So, in the case which you have suggested, how will i set my theme on domain.com/collection/

Comment: Set the theme across the entire site.  Go find `home` in the CMS, and apply a different template on the `design` tab.

Comment: Alright, i have to create 2 CMS page and have to change the template from design tab for both of them. Am i right.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83116/discussion-between-douglas-radburn-and-soeb-safi).

Answer (score 0):

To add an answer from our comments...

You are wanting to have a homepage, and a landing page - you should edit the `home` (identifier) and set it up as required - with layout or theme.

Additionally, you should then create a new page, for example `collections` that you open in a new tab when appropriate - i.e. on click of a CTA.  As this is a separate page, you can apply a different layout, or theme to this second page.